# Why cannot a file have both a primary index and clustering index?

Tags: database

I was reading this statement in some notes i found online about index in database. "A file can have at most one primary index or one clustering index, but not both."
Why cannot a file have both a primary index and clustering index? is it because a file can have at most one physical ordering field?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of database do you talking about? In "common" databases this not truth. Or the "file" is in different meaning than file in storage.

Comment: "I was reading this statement in some notes i found online" - provide a link, so that we can see what is being said **in context**.  (Also, note that relying on any random notes that you found online is unwise ... unless you are happy to believe that the earth is flat, JFK was abducted by aliens, etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry if i didn't provide the link. Of course, i'm looking at a reliable source since i got this online notes from a university. I am researching some stuff before i ask question so i don't look stupid or anything. Thank you though.

www.just.edu.jo/~amerb/teaching/2-10-11/cs728/ch17.ppt

this is the link i was looking that time... It is is PPT file At slide 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generated (primary) clustered index is the primary index, that is why you cannot have both.

If you declare one column as the primary index and is valid the database will use that.

If you don't declare one column as the primary index but have one column that is unique, not null, and has a value that can be indexed, for example `int` or a fixed lenght `char`, but not a `text` or `blob` column, the system will use that as the primary index.

If you don't have *one* column that fits the criteria, then the system will try to find a group of columns that fit the criteria and use that as the primary (clustered) index.

If that is still not possible then it will create a hidden column and index the table using that column internally.

But the statement itself is not really correct, you could have a primary key, clustered or not and still have some clustered secondary indexes.

What the statement is saying is that **you cannot have two primary indexes in one table.**

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. It really helps!